# Подключение к MySQL из AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

На AWS развернута база MySQL, на языке python с помощью библиотеки pymysql, с локального компа подключаюсь к базе, но когда этот код переношу в AWS Lambda то выдает ошибку. Код переносится с сопутствующими библиотеками. Подскажите с чем может быть связана ошибка? С AWS работаю 2-й день)

```
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mydbinstance.*******.us-east- 
2.rds.amazonaws.com' (timed out)"): OperationalError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/main.py", line 8, in getHello
rez = getAll()
File "/var/task/main.py", line 34, in getAll conn=pymysql.connect(host=host,user=user,password=password,database=database,connect 
_timeout=15)
File "/var/task/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/task/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
self.connect()
File "/var/task/pymysql/connections.py", line 630, in connect
raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 
'mydbinstance.*******.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (timed out)")
```

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался, на самом деле у моей лямбда функции пропал доступ в интернет. Вдруг кому понадобиться вот [ссылка](https://medium.com/@philippholly/aws-lambda-enable-outgoing-internet-access-within-vpc-8dd250e11e12)